# Commutativity of weak partial derivatives. Don't follow proof.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

The proof of commutativity of weak partial derivatives is given in Evans PDE textbook but I really don't follow any of it. If someone could walk me through it I would be extremely grateful. Sorry that I can't comment with what I've tried as I really haven't got very far.  Thanks

> Assume $u,v \in W^{k,p}(U)$, $|\alpha|\leq k$. 
>   Then $D^\alpha u \in W^{k-|\alpha|,p}(U)$ and $D^\beta (D^\alpha u)=D^\alpha (D^\beta u)=D^{\alpha+\beta} u$ for all multiindices $\alpha, \beta$ with $|\alpha|+|\beta|\leq k$

Proof

> Fix $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$. Then $D^\beta \phi \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$ and so
>   \begin{align}
> \int_U D^\alpha u D^\beta \phi\;dx&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_U uD^{\alpha+\beta}\phi\;dx \\ &=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(-1)^{|\alpha+\beta|}\int_U D^{\alpha+\beta}u\phi\;dx \\ &=(-1)^{|\beta|}\int_U D^{\alpha+\beta}u\phi\;dx
> \end{align}

Many thanks.

Comment: While others are advising you, would you advise me? I am an engineer rather than a mathematician. What kind of notation is $\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$? If you told me that it were, say, *Smith's extruded topology notation,* then I would go to look that up, because I would like to learn to read what you just wrote. (I hold a master's degree in engineering with focus in electromagnetics, so I can handle fairly heavy computations, PDEs, special functions, etc.; only I cannot read some of this notation. This is why I ask.)

Comment: So from Evans textbook. "Let $C^\infty_c(U)$ denote the space of infinitely differentiable functions $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with compact support in $U$.We will call a function $\phi$ belonging to $C^\infty_c(U)$ a test function". I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Evans' primary goal here is not to prove that weak derivatives commute, but rather, to prove that there exists a $\beta$th weak derivative for $D^\alpha u$, namely:
$$ D^\beta(D^\alpha u) = D^{\alpha + \beta} u.$$
[If $|\alpha| + |\beta| < k$, then the $\alpha$th and $(\alpha + \beta)$th weak derivatives of $u$ exist *by assumption*, and they are denoted by $D^\alpha u$ and $D^{\alpha + \beta}u$ respectively; our task is to prove that $D^\alpha u$ has a $\beta$th weak derivative, equal to $D^{\alpha + \beta} u$.]

However, once Evans has proved this, the commutativity of weak derivatives follows immediately, from the symmetry between $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

So what does it mean to say that the $\beta$th weak derivative of a locally summable function $v$ (say) is equal to a locally summable function $w$ (say)? It means that, for all test functions $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$,
$$ \int_U vD^\beta \phi = (-1)^{|\beta|} \int_Uw \phi. $$
In our case, $v=D^\alpha u$ and $w = D^{\alpha + \beta} u$, so our task is to prove that
$$ \int_U D^\alpha u D^\beta \phi = (-1)^{|\beta|} \int_U D^{\alpha + \beta}u  \phi \ \ \ \ (\ast)$$
for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$.

To prove this, first recall that $D^{\alpha + \beta}u$ is by definition the $(\alpha + \beta)$th weak derivative of $u$. Therefore, for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$:
$$ \int_U D^{\alpha + \beta} u \phi = (-1)^{|\alpha| + |\beta|} \int_U u D^{\alpha + \beta} \phi$$
Also, $D^{\alpha + \beta} \phi$ is equal to $D^\alpha ( D^\beta \phi)$. (Remember, these are genuine, not weak, derivatives of $\phi$!). So:
$$  \int_U u D^{\alpha + \beta} \phi =  \int_U u D^{\alpha } ( D^\beta \phi) $$
Next, observe that $D^\beta \phi$ is in $C_c^\infty(U)$! So applying the statement that $D^\alpha u$ is the $\alpha$th weak derivative of $u$, with $D^\beta\phi$ as the "test function" instead of $\phi$, we learn that
$$ \int_U u D^{\alpha}( D^\beta \phi ) = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_U D^\alpha u D^\beta \phi $$
Combining the two equations above gives the desired result $(\ast)$.

Finally, we can say a little more about $D^\alpha u$. Its $\beta$th weak derivative, being equal to $D^{\alpha + \beta}u$, is in $L^p(U)$. This is true for any $\beta$ such that $|\beta | < k - |\alpha|$. Hence $D^\alpha u$ is in $W^{k - |\alpha|, p}(U)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It's really excellent. The one thing I'm not too sure about is the line with three integral terms. In particular, $(-1)^{|\alpha|+|\beta|} \int_U uD^{\alpha+\beta}\phi=(-1)^{|\alpha|+|\beta|} \int_U uD^{\alpha}(D^{\beta}\phi)$ In this case are we not assuming something we aim to prove.

Comment: @mark Please see the edit. Any better?

Comment: Ah sorry! I see what you mean. That was me not thinking straight. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again. After working through some more of the properties of weak derivatives in Evans I've become stuck on proving the Leibniz rule for weak derivatives. I've had a look at the following question on here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866286/evanss-proof-of-the-leibnizs-formula-for-the-weak-derivatives-in-sobolev-space  I dont suppose you could tell me how to from A to B to C? I don't want to take up too much of your time so If you can't that's completely fine. Thanks for your previous answer anyway.

Comment: Hi @mark, I would love to help but I don't think I can find time to look at this tonight, I'm afraid. But you could post a separate question, with a link to the original question and an explanation of which part is not clear. There are plenty of excellent people on this site, so I'm sure you'll get a good answer! :)

Comment: That's ok. I appreciate your help anyway. I may post again tomorrow if I don't make process. Thanks.